# Pinterest v3 api OAuth documentation

Tags: c#, oauth, uri, pinterest, callbackurl

I want to access this following endpoint of Pinterest :
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/search/pins/?join=via_pinner,board,pinner&page_size=50&query=Red&access_token=APIKEY

I have gone through https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/signature/ to create APIKEY. When I click on "Sign It" button of signature tool I get popup with message "You are not permitted to access this resource".

My question is how to get APIKEY for pinterest, I have researched a lot but no luck.

Thanks in advance!